# Error in object file while compiling on gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have several .h files which are included in the beginning of a .c file.

When I compile the .c file using the -c flag :

```
gcc -Wall -c parserv9-3.c
```

There are no errors, or any warnings.

However when I remove the -c flag it gives an error in the temporary object file.

That is, when I run

```
gcc -Wall parserv9-3.c
```

I get the following error :

```
/tmp/cc5IWBiC.o: In function `parseInputSourceCode':
parserv9-3.c:(.text+0x204b): undefined reference to `getStream'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-c` flag means compile only, not link. When you remove it - gcc will also link the object into an executable (invoke the ld command, rather), and then it must find all the referenced external symbols.

In your case, the symbol `getStream` doesn't exist. It's probably in a different .c file.

Comment: Yes, the function `getStream` exists in a different .c file but it is declared in one of the .h files that the current .c is including.

So how do I use that same function without copying the whole code to this .c file?

Comment: when you **link** - you should link all the objects together. Compiler doesn't care about where the actual implementation is, the linker does. If you do "gcc file1.c file2.c -o exec" - you can call functions implemented in file1 from file2 and it will link. But you have to link them **together**. Otherwise, you can compile, create o/so/a/lib/dll/whatever, but it will have to be linked with the actual implementation eventually.